# C string to uppercase in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, string, uppercase, c-strings

While I was putting together a to-uppercase function in C++ I noticed that I did not receive the expected output in C.

**C++ function**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>

void strupp(char* beg)
{
    while (*beg++ = std::toupper(*beg));
}

int main(int charc, char* argv[])
{
    char a[] = "foobar";
    strupp(a);
    printf("%s\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output as expected:

```
FOOBAR
```

---

**C function**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strupp(char* beg)
{
    while (*beg++ = toupper(*beg));
}

int main(int charc, char* argv[])
{
    char a[] = "foobar";
    strupp(a);
    printf("%s\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the expected result with the first character missing

```
OOBAR
```

Does anyone know why the result gets truncated while compiling in C?

Comment: And if you really wanted to do this in `C++`:  `std::transform(a, a + strlen(a), a, std::toupper);`

Comment: Can you explain why you expected this to convert a string to uppercase? Specifically, why did you expect the right side of the `=` to be evaluated before the left?

Comment: I'm thankful to all people who gave feedback and for the valuable info provided

Comment: Also add cast: `while (*beg = toupper((unsigned char) *beg)) beg++;`.  `toupper()` is not well defined for negative `char` values.

Comment: Don't write so complex code if you don't understand sequence points and operation priorities. And even if you understand them - care about your colleagues, write each statement on a new line.

Comment: @Schullz I strongly believe that learning from your mistakes is the most efficient way not to make the same mistake again. Hence as this problem stemmed solely from experimentation and not in a team project environment I don't think it was a mistake to write this code snippet to begin with

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, The docs for `std::transform` state that "std::transform does not guarantee in-order application of unary_op or binary_op. To apply a function to a sequence in-order or to apply a function that modifies the elements of a sequence, use std::for_each".

Comment: So then something like `std::for_each(a, a + strlen(a), [](char &c){ c = std::toupper(c); });`?

Comment: @MillieSmith In this case, does it matter the order of which item will be made upper case?  Anyway, most, if not all of the classical C++ approaches of mutating a string use `std::transform`.

Comment: @AlexKoukoulas i think so about learning from mistakes. What about trying doing experiments with different compilers? It could be interesting :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that there is no sequence point in

```
while (*beg++ = toupper(*beg));
```

So we have undefined behavior.  What the compiler is doing in this case is evaluating `beg++` before `toupper(*beg)` In C where in C++ it is doing it the other way.

Comment: Does this mean that the classic c-string copying one-liner `while(*s++ = *t++) ;` has undefined behavior?

Comment: @markh No as that is two different variables.  This is synonymous with `while (*s++ = *s++)`

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually, `while(*s++ = *t++);` has defined behaviour even if `s == t`. The reason `strcpy` is undefined with overlapping regions is that `strcpy` isn't necessarily implemented with `while(*s++ = *t++);`.

Comment: @immibis: fair point, agreed it's defined. However, even if `strcpy` is implemented with that loop it still has undefined behavior for one "direction" of overlap. If the destination is greater than the source and they overlap, then the terminating nul gets overwritten before it's read, and eventually the buffer is overrun! The reason overlap is forbidden in both "directions" is for possible other implementations.

Answer (score 15):

```
while (*beg++ = std::toupper(*beg));
```

leads to undefined behavior.

Whether `*beg++` is sequenced before or after `std::toupper(*beg)` is unspecified.

The simple fix is to use:

```
while (*beg = std::toupper(*beg))
   ++beg;
```

Answer (score 10):

The line

```
while (*beg++ = toupper(*beg));
```

contains a side effect on an entity that's being used twice. You can not know, whether or not beg++ is executed before or after the *beg (inside the toupper). You're just lucky that both implementations show both behaviors, as I'm pretty sure it's the same for C++. (However, there were some rule changes for c++11, which I'm not certain of - still, it's bad style.)

Just move the beg++ out of the condition:

```
while (*beg = toupper(*beg)) beg++;
```

Answer (score 3):

with respect to above answer, the 'f' is never passed inside function, you should try using this:

```
     while ((*beg = (char) toupper(*beg))) beg++;
```

Comment: casting to char was important as value of type int may not fit into receiver type char

Comment: That cast achieves nothing that wouldn't happen without it anyway.